# Using jQuery validate to add the totals of two inputs?

Tags: jquery

I have a form with two input fields and a display text div:

```
<div id="message">Display message Here</div>
<form id="logged_in" action="" method="post">
   <label>Item 1</label>
   <input id="item_1" type="text" />
   <label>Item 2</label>
   <input id="item_2" type="text" />
</form>
```

So far I am using jQuery validate to check that both inputs are only receiving digits (works). But how do I set it up so that when the user enters input into those inputs and presses "tab", the inputs from both "item_1" and "item_2" are added together and then displayed inside of #message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#item_1, #item_2').blur(function(){
    var item_1 = $('#item_1').val(),
        item_1 = item_1.length ? parseInt(item_1) : 0,
        item_2 = $('#item_2').val(),
        item_2 = item_2.length ? parseInt(item_2) : 0;
    $('#message').text(item_1+item_2);
});
```

[**Here is a demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/LVNdF/)

Answer (score 1):

Only on pressing tab, or when the fields lose focus? This is for every situation:

```
$( function() {
    $( '#item_1, #item_2' ).blur( function() {
        $( '#message' ).html( parseInt( $( '#item_1' ).val() ) + parseInt( $( '#item_2' ).val() ) );
    } );
} );
```

You probably need to add a check that there is a value in both fields, otherwise you might end up with a NaN.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#item_2').blur(function(){
    $('#message').html(
        parseInt($('#item_1').val()) + parseInt($('#item_2').val())
    );
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Jacek_FH/QKbXV/

Answer (score 0):

probably something like this should work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("input").change(function(){
    sum = 0;
    $("input").each(function(){
      sum += $(this).val();
    });
    $("#message").html("The sum is: " + sum);
  });
});
```

Here's a [link](http://jsfiddle.net/vAXH4/).

This should work for any number of inputs also.

Answer (score 0):

You can execute a function on the input's obBlur event to verify that both values have been entered, and if so, perform the add and update the message elements content.

http://jsfiddle.net/CBHBT/

Answer (score 0):

While you can target it specifically with the key event for Tab, your user may use a different method to lose focus, which is why .blur() would be a better approach.

This solution works around the parseInt bug in some browsers, which can be very annoying if not accounted for:

```
$('#item_1, #item_2').blur(function () {
    var i1 = parseFloat($("#item_1").val());
    var i2 = parseFloat($("#item_2").val());
    if(!isNaN(i1) && !isNaN(i2)){
        var r = parseFloat(i1+i2);
        $("#message").html(r);
    }
});
```